# Efeito de rolagem com a recyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragment

Eu estou trabalhando em um aplicativo em que tenho uma fragment com um titulo e uma recyclerView. Essa recycler view está dividida em sessões (exemplo, pizza, refrigerante), cada sessão tem um cabeçalho e os itens que o pertence. O que eu quero fazer nessa lista é um efeito, que quando eu rolo a lista a toolbar fique com o nome da sessão que está aparecendo na tela e sendo rolada no momento. Algo parecido com o aplicativo Briefieng de notícias  ( quem tem um smartphone da Samsung mais recente sabe que app é esse). Nem sei qual é o nome desse efeito. Procurei algo no google mas não achei. Se alguém puder me ajudar, será ótimo. Obrigada

Comment: Dê uma olhada [nesta library](https://github.com/S64/android-sticky-recycler)

Comment: Obrigada, eu olhei a biblioteca

Comment: Me ajudou a saber o nome do efeito e a pesquisar mais sobre como implementar. Fiz sem o uso de uma lib, pra entender o funcionamento. Agora o único problema que encontrei na implementação é que, quando faço a rolagem da página o header some antes do outro header chegar no topo. Obrigada pela ajuda, e se puder me ajudar com mais esse problema, agradeço :)